# std::enable_if vs hard errors in non-immediate context

Tags: c++, sfinae

According to the despcription of SFINAE on [cpprefence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type or its template parameter types or its explicit specifier (since C++20) are SFINAE errors. If the evaluation of a substituted type/expression causes a side-effect such as instantiation of some template specialization, generation of an implicitly-defined member function, etc, errors in those side-effects are treated as hard errors.

In particular, when `Helper<T>` in my code below is instantiated during template argument deduction I'm getting an error, as expected. So here is my question: Why `std::enable_if` works well with 
SFINAE, even though it is a struct that must be instantiated (and is typically used with 
a lot of type-traits structs that are also instantiated in the process).

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U = typename T::my_type>
void sfinae(const T&) { std::cout << "template\n"; }

void sfinae(...) { std::cout << "non template\n"; }

template<typename T>
struct Helper{
    using my_type = typename T::my_type;
};

template<typename T, typename U = typename Helper<T>::my_type>
void hardError(const T&) { std::cout << "template\n"; }

void hardError(...) { std::cout << "non template\n"; }


struct NonEmpty{ using my_type=int; };
struct Empty{ };


int main()
{
    NonEmpty ne;
    Empty e;

    sfinae(ne);     //template overload called
    hardError(ne);  //template overload called

    sfinae(e);      //non-template overload called

    hardError(e);   //hard error 

}
```

Comment: I don't see any `std::enable_if` used here. And it is not supposed to be used in the manner similar to `Helper<T>`. And its instantiation can not fail cause of being ill-formed, like `Helper<T>` does when `T` does not have `my_type` member.

Comment: @user7860670 The use of std::enable_if is a bit similar. Typical use is std::enable_if<CONDITION<T> >::type, and we don't get hard error even though the struct does not have the type member

Comment: @user7860670 I guess, I start to understand the difference. So you are saying that std::enable_if<CONDITION<T>> is instantiated without any problems, even if CONDITION<T>==false. And sfinae works because the (successufully instantiated) struct does not have the type member. While it is the instantantation of my Helper<T> that fails when T does not have the type memeber, correct?

Comment: Correct. `enable_if` can not be broken by supplying some sort of unfitting template parameter.

Comment: @user7860670 OK, thanks a lot (I still need to process this, though).

Comment: @user7860670: Within limits. `sizeof(void)` is still going to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible implementation for `std::enable_if` is

```
template <bool cond, typename T = void> struct enable_if;
template <typename T> struct enable_if<false, T>{};
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T>{ using type = T; };
```

So `enable_if` doesn't produce hard error. instantiating `std::enable_if<false>` is valid.

Instantiating `Helper<Empty>` produces an error on `Empty::type`, which is not done in immediate context of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), so the hard error.

`std::enable_if` and `std::void_t` works well with SFINAE as they provide easy way to fail in immediate context:

`std::enable_if<cond_v<T>, int>::type = 0` or `typename AlwaysVoid = std::void_t<decltype(dependent_expression)>`.